# Onchange show incorrect the value in the input fields

Tags: javascript, php, onchange

I have a problem make the onchange function to get the correct value. I want show the value in the 8 input fields if I select the option. Below is my select function coding:

```html
<select onchange="getComboA(this)" class="form-control blank" id="parentid" name="parentid" title="parentid">
                  <option>Please Select</option>
                  <option value="New Category_value" 
                  data-function-code="' . $rs_incharge['function_code'] . '"
                  data-function-name="' . $rs_incharge['function_name'] . '" 
                  data-activity-code="' . $rs_incharge['activity_code'] . '" 
                  data-activity-name="' . $rs_incharge['activity_name'] . '" 
                  data-sub-activity-code="' . $rs_incharge['sub_activity_code'] . '" 
                  data-sub-activity-name="' . $rs_incharge['sub_activity_name'] . '" 
                  data-transaction-code="' . $rs_incharge['transaction_code'] . '"  
                  data-transaction-name="' . $rs_incharge['transaction_name'] . '"> New Category
                </option>
                  <?php
                    $sql_incharge = 'select * from filing_code_management where status=1 order by id';
                    $arr_incharge = db_conn_select($sql_incharge);
                    foreach ($arr_incharge as $rs_incharge) {
                    $folder_location = $rs_incharge['folder_location'];
            $function_code_select = $rs_incharge['function_code'];
            $function_name_select = $rs_incharge['function_name'];
            $activity_code_select = $rs_incharge['activity_code'];
            $activity_name_select = $rs_incharge['activity_name'];
            $sub_activity_code_select = $rs_incharge['sub_activity_code'];
            $sub_activity_name_select = $rs_incharge['sub_activity_name'];
            $transaction_code_select = $rs_incharge['transaction_code'];
            $transaction_name_select = $rs_incharge['transaction_name'];
                    echo '<option value="' . $rs_incharge['function_code'] . '">' . $rs_incharge['name'] . '</option>';

                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Jquery function:

```html
<script>
    function getComboA() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('parentid');
    var selected = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-function-code');
    document.getElementById("function_code").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-function-name');
    document.getElementById("function_name").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-activity-code');
    document.getElementById("activity_code").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-activity-name');
    document.getElementById("activity_name").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-sub-activity-code');
    document.getElementById("sub_activity_code").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-sub-activity-name');
    document.getElementById("sub_activity_name").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-transaction-code');
    document.getElementById("transaction_code").value =data;
    var data = selected.getAttribute('data-transaction-name');
    document.getElementById("transaction_name").value =data;
  }

</script>
```

Below is the error output, it cannot show the correct value, just show me the variable name when I am selected category. And if I select other selection, it also cannot show me the value:

**Select Category**

[image: Output 1]

**Select other name no value to show out**

[image: Output 2]

Whole code: https://pastebin.com/9vyvL0SG

Hope someone can guide me how to show out correct the value in the 8 input fields.

Comment: @Barmar Can you guide me solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see where your PHP code starts, try this:

```
<select onchange="getComboA(this)" class="form-control blank" id="parentid" name="parentid" title="parentid">
    <option>Please Select</option>

    <?php
        $sql_incharge = 'select * from filing_code_management where status=1 order by id';
        $arr_incharge = db_conn_select($sql_incharge);
        foreach ($arr_incharge as $rs_incharge) {
            $folder_location = $rs_incharge['folder_location'];
            $function_code_select = $rs_incharge['function_code'];
            echo '<option value="' . $rs_incharge['function_code'] . '">' . $rs_incharge['name'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>

    <option value="New Category_value" 
        data-function-code="<?php echo $rs_incharge['function_code']; ?>"
        data-function-name="<?php echo $rs_incharge['function_name']; ?>" 
        data-activity-code="<?php echo $rs_incharge['activity_code']; ?>" 
        data-activity-name="<?php echo $rs_incharge['activity_name']; ?>" 
        data-sub-activity-code="<?php echo $rs_incharge['sub_activity_code']; ?>" 
        data-sub-activity-name="<?php echo $rs_incharge['sub_activity_name']; ?>" 
        data-transaction-code="<?php echo $rs_incharge['transaction_code']; ?>"  
        data-transaction-name="<?php echo $rs_incharge['transaction_name']; ?>"> New Category
    </option>
</select>
```

I assume `$rs_incharge['function_code']` is already defined before `<select onchange...`

---

Example below will work cause we define `$variable` **BEFORE** we use `echo`:

```
<?php
    $variable = 'This is awesome!';
    echo $variable;
?>
```

Example below will give ERROR cause we define `$variable` **AFTER** `echo`:

```
<?php
    echo $variable;
    $variable = 'This is awesome!';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried your code, cannot show the value in the input fields. And I also update my question

Comment: @SunnyOng in your code on line 4: `$rs_incharge['function_code']` where do you get this from? To debug add this line before line4: `<?php die(var_dump($rs_incharge)); ?>` what result you get?

Comment: I have tried to paste whole code here https://pastebin.com/9vyvL0SG

Comment: $rs_incharge['function_code'] is get the data from the database

Comment: @SunnyOng I checked full code. The problem is on line 4. When we ask PHP to echo like: `<?php echo $rs_incharge['function_code']; ?>` at that time `$rs_incharge['function_code']` is not defined. You need to get data from database **BEFORE** you start using it. So first GET data from database, after that start using it. I updated the code. Please check.

Comment: How to get data from database BEFORE I start using it

Comment: I updated my answer. As you see I added your PHP code where it gets data from database before line 4 in your code.

Comment: I using your update, no value show in the input fields

Comment: @SunnyOng you are NOT connecting to database correctly, where did you define the username + password + database IP/location for database? Google: **PHP connect to mysql**

Comment: Thanks. I've settled it.